# PDF conversion lose format when is converted by Docx4j

Tags: java, pdf, docx, docx4j

I've a problem when pass file from **.docx** to **pdf**.

I use docx4j 3.2.2, the code for conversion:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

public class PDFConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createPDF();
    }

    private static void createPDF() {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("docxFile"));
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("pdfFile"));
            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, out);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the conversion is realiced, but pdf lose the format, here the original docx and pdf conversion

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEFdh.png)

[Conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZso1.png)

#### This is because is needed some configuration?

regards.

Comment: I can't use another version of docx4j, is a poop, but that is

Comment: The same happens with apache poi

Comment: You'll need to put the original docx somewhere for us to look at.

Comment: here is my doc example. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5Tek4bWFzo0ZnlEV2hKdzNPZ1E?usp=sharing)

Finally I could keep the format, but not at all

Comment: additional info:

I can change de version, now use a docx4j 3.3.0

Comment: So is the issue that the original is multi column while the output is single column?

Comment: Yes @BrandonHaugen , the problem was a multi column and the output a single column. this problem is almost resolved with the docx4j 3.3.0, now the problem is in the next link [test](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5Tek4bWFzo0ZnlEV2hKdzNPZ1E?usp=sharing).

the conversion is through FOS method (Docx4j.toFO), the output of the document is in multi column.

the link contains original document and conversion.

thanks. Sorry for my english.

Comment: is resolved: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41435372/6561465)

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.xxx.ecm.converter

import com.xxx.ecm.api.object.model.BaseContent
import org.docx4j.Docx4J
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage

class Docx2PdfConverter extends Converter 
{
    InputStream convert(BaseContent content) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = content.inputStream.bytes
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.size())
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is)
            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, outputStream);
            new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more for beginners ?