# Docx4j throws exception when convert to pdf

Tags: jboss6.x, docx4j

this excpetion is throw in web application, but in a stand alone application not happen this. Any idea, i use docx4j 3.3.0.

The application runing Jboss 6.3 eap.

Before a use an older version (3.2.2) but not throws this error.

```
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    net.solser.admc.filter.RequestSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestSecurityFilter.java:48)
    net.solser.filter.compress.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:35)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
    org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:592)
    net.solsersistem.utils.pdf.PDFUtils.convertDocx4jToPDF(PDFUtils.java:45)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownload(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1190)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownloadAndDeleteFile(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1203)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.downloadDraftContract(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:349)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    net.solser.admc.filter.RequestSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestSecurityFilter.java:48)
    net.solser.filter.compress.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:35)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest from [Module "deployment.EARAdmContractRest.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:592)
    net.solsersistem.utils.pdf.PDFUtils.convertDocx4jToPDF(PDFUtils.java:45)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownload(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1190)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.sendFileToDownloadAndDeleteFile(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:1203)
    net.solser.admc.service.purchasingflow.PurchasingRequisitionService.downloadDraftContract(PurchasingRequisitionService.java:349)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    net.solser.admc.filter.RequestSecurityFilter.doFilter(RequestSecurityFilter.java:48)
    net.solser.filter.compress.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:35)
```

tanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are converting to PDF.

As per the release notes at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-3-3-0-released-t2381.html things changed in v3.3.x:

> default PDF converter changed from XSL FO + Apache FOP to Plutext's
>   commercial PDF Converter. XSL FO based PDF output moved to
>   new/separate project docx4j-export-fo; We made this change after
>   careful consideration, since the quality/performance is so much
>   better, and it removes various dependencies from docx4j itself. If you
>   want to stick with the existing XSL FO + Apache FOP PDF Conversion, no
>   probs:- see below for how.
>
> The instance of PDF Converter at converter-eval.plutext.com is used by
>   default, but you can (and should!) install it locally; installers are
>   available at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/
>
> To use your own instance, set docx4j property, eg:
>
> com.plutext.converter.URL=http://converter-eval.plutext.com:80/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert
>
> If you want to use the existing XSL FO + Apache FOP PDF Conversion,
>   just add docx4j-export-fo (+ deps) to your classpath. If these are
>   present, docx4j will revert to the FO based conversion. These jars are
>   in the zip file, in dir optional/export-fo and also in Maven Central.

When using the default PDF Converter (ie the commercial one), you need the relevant docx4j 3.x dependencies, in this case, https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/pom.xml#L502

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: that´s it, only i add another dependency:
**org.apache.httpcomponents: httpcore**